# Preventing decimals from entering into a column - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was wondering if there's a way to prevent data of number type from entering into a table if the value of the number is not a whole number.

ie. If the data contains fractions or decimals, I do not want to store the data. I am using oracle 11g. Despite defining the scale as 0, oracle would round off the decimal part of the number to the nearest integer.

Pretty sure we'd have to have some sort of check constraint on the column, but am not quite sure what that would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an integer type you can use?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Oracle seems to rounds off the value to the nearest integer for Integer type too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For smaller fractions, perhaps use float?

(since adding scale to the number only worked for the range defined)

```
drop table whole_numbers;
create table whole_numbers(a float);
alter table whole_numbers add constraint check_whole check (a = trunc(a));

insert into whole_numbers values(1);

1 row inserted.

insert into whole_numbers values(1.00002);

ORA-02290: check constraint (VBSMASTER.CHECK_WHOLE) violated
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check

*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had the type set as NUMBER(2,0) all this while.

Comment: It works for most cases, but it still allows the values which exceed the scale and are close to the either higher bound integer or lower bound integer values. For scale 2, if we give 12.9999 or 10.0001, it accepts the values without throwing in error. 

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: I tried that way initially and was a little confused myself. It was just automatically truncating to fit, the check was useless. And now I see you're finding issues with smaller fractions. You could have a trigger that checks for this and raise_application_error if necessary, but there must be a more elegant solution.

Comment: In other words, it's converting the input value to the column type, using something like `CAST ( 12.9999 as NUMBER(5,2) )`, before it even gets to the check constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_col_int as (col = trunc(col));
```

However, it might make more sense to just declare the column as an integer or a numeric with no decimal places.  Hmmmm, that might not do what you want, because an input real/floating point number would be converted rather than generating an error.

Comment: Precisely my point. It gets stored as an integer rather than throwing an error.

Comment: The above check constraint didn't seem to help much. It's still storing the integer part of the number.

Comment: How about `alter table t add constraint chk_col_int as (ceil(col) = floor(col)) enable;`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff :It worked. However like Scott mentioned, it only worked after I modified the column type from NUMBER(2,0) to NUMBER(3,1).  

May be I should have included the precision and the scale.

Comment: @kfinity  Well may be, I spoke a little soon.  It almost did the trick for both the answers. But it failed to throw an error and started storing when the inputted numbers exceeded the defined scale and is close to either high bound integer or low bound integer. Say you defined the scale as 2 for the NUMBER(3,2) and tried entering 1.99999 or 1.00002. The values gets stored as 2 or 1. This behavior is weird as ceil and floor values would never be equal for any given decimal value. I could probably see why 1.000002 could get stored, but 1.99999 beats me.